# How to install myapp silently without user interaction?

Tags: install4j

How to install my application silently without user interaction, few screens seeks the user inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

install4j has an unattended mode that can be activated by passing the command line parameter `-q`.

If you want mode to be the default behavior with a progress bar that shows status messages, go to "Installer->Screens & Actions", select the installer node and set the "Default execution mode" property to "Unattended mode with progress dialog".

Comment: How can i pass the input's with -q option ?

Comment: With a response file: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/responseFile.html